# MathJax display issues within iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, mathjax

I have been using the Stack Exchange app on my iPhone for three months or four. Generally this app is really appreciated, which provides a relatively quicker connection to this site and a freer browsing experience. But here is a very frequent problem that I have been encountering within this app - the MathJax display often looks out of order under certain circumstances. (Although on the computer these problems are usually gone)

I've got two examples here that represent two kinds of Jax display problems within this iOS app:

The first is the "overlap" problem. The screenshot below is the famous MathJax tutorial post. This is not the only case where the overlap occurs (it's just I happened to browse this page and just caught it), in fact there are really **many** cases.

> [image]

The second is the "overflow" problem, which is much more common to be seen. The screenshot is an answer by @Oliver Oloa. Since it is **impossible to scroll horizontally** within iOS app, it's my impression that whenever a line is too long for the mobile phone screen, the overflowing part will be missing.

> [image]

I have to confess that these two display problems do cause some inconvenience sometimes, especially the "overflow" problem. Could anybody help? (Is it ok to ask here?).

I know it's perhaps all because iPhone screen is too small to display a very long line which, however, would look just ok on PC.  But I guess there would always be ways to solve such problems. Maybe forcibly break a long line into smaller lines so that the iPhone screen can hold?

---

For the second problem, now I think maybe it's not necessary nor proper to forcibly break the lines, perhaps all that is needed to do is enable scrolling horizontally within iOS app.

Comment: Original post on Math Meta: [MathJax display issues within iOS app](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20487/mathjax-display-issues-within-ios-app)

Comment: @HDE226868 thanks. Maybe I shoulda included the origin post here.

Comment: Also, the question technically hasn't been migrated; it's merely been cross-posted, which isn't as good. You can flag the original post for mod attention to migrate it here, and then have it merged with this one.

Comment: @HDE226868 thank you.  I didn't know that I could do it this way. But would that take more time to attract moderator attention and migrate than directly repost like this?

Comment: Yes, but it would make things neater. SE isn't a huge fan of cross-posting, as it spreads out related discussions.

Comment: @HDE226868. Ok.  I will re-do it as you said.

Comment: @HDE226868 but how to delete this one?

Comment: There should be a button somewhere, near the "edit" button.

Comment: @HDE226868. Strange enough I can't find the delete button. But in other sites than Meta SE I can.

Comment: There is really no need to delete bug reports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second issue will be fixed in the next build by adding horizontal scrolling.  This only applies to display math not inline.

I've also upgraded the app from MathJax 2.1 to 2.5.3 but this hasn't solved issue of `\tag{displayed}` overlapping the equation.  According to [Peter's answer on the other post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20492/239857) it's a known issue in MathJax.

[image: Screenshot of wide math with scrollbar]

Comment: Thank you! Adding scrolling is really appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. A fix for the overlap should make it into our next release.